# SQL: ALTER TABLE to create columns from a list if they don´t exist

Tags: sql, sas

I want to check which columns doesn´t exist in a table using a list with stored columns and create  that with certain value. Is there a option to do this without having to name manually the columns? I mean getting the name from the list and create the column with that information.
It would be something like:

```
    proc sql;
    select name into:varlist separated by ', '
    from table
    where column like 'name%'; (Every column will have the same name but 
    different suffix)
    quit;

    ALTER TABLE table_name 
    ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS column_name tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0;
```

Comment: `Every column will have the same name but different suffix` ... obviously we don't have the full details but this requirement sounds like it's probably the result of a design mistake where you should actually have some secondary table with a foreign key, and define this data in rows rather than columns

Comment: Are you doing this with SAS datasets?  Why not just create an empty dataset with all the variables you want?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably easier to do with dictionary tables.

```
data have;
    var_1 = 1;
    var_3 = 1;
    var_5 = 1;
run;

/* Create a table with all variables that you need */
data need;
    array var_[5];
run;

/* Compare the template table variables to actual */
proc sql noprint;
    select name
         , 0 as init
    into :varlist separated by ' '
       , :init    separated by ' '
    from dictionary.columns
    where     libname = 'WORK'
          AND memname = 'NEED'
          AND name NOT IN
            (select name
             from dictionary.columns
             where     libname = 'WORK'
                   AND memname = 'HAVE'
                   AND name LIKE 'var_%'
            )
    ;
quit;

/* Add the new variables to the table */
data want;
    set have;
    array var[*] &varlist. (&init.);
run;
```

Output:

```
var_1   var_3   var_5   var_2   var_4
1       1       1       0       0
```